# Trouble aligning content inside v-row or v-col in Vuetify.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I am having issues aligning things correctly inside my Vue app using Vuetify.

```html
<v-card class="mx-auto">
  <v-row>
    <v-col
      v-for="(item, i) in items"
      :key="i"
      align-end
      justify-end
    >
      <v-btn class="btn">
        <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
        <span class="ml-2">{{ item.text }}</span>
      </v-btn>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
  ...
```

I simply want to align it to the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The properties you've put on `<v-col>` don't exist (i.e. align-end and justify-end). They are properties on the `<v-row>` component (which is a flex container). You need to use classes instead.

Make sure to consult the API->props section on the Vuetify component page when choosing component properties.

Try

```html
<v-col class="d-flex justify-end">
    <v-btn>Button</v-btn>
</v-col>
```

Note that the alignment is dependent upon the width of v-col. If v-col is only as wide as the button, you'll need to set the width by using the cols="x" property.

Comment: Actually i went with a similar solution, but with v-card instead. This worked for me

`<v-card class="d-flex justify-end">`

Comment: Glad you got it fixed. If my answer helped, I'd really appreciate your marking it as correct by clicking the tick-mark below the upvote/downvote buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Add `direction: rtl` to your `v-btn`, Here is [codepen](https://codepen.io/MNSY22/pen/qBqWZEv):

```html
<template>
  <v-btn class="btn rtl">
  ...
  </v-btn>
</template>

<style>
.rtl { direction: rtl; }
</style>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't what they were asking, but even if, using a language feature of CSS is not the correct way to go about this.

You could easily use `display: flex; flex-flow: row-reverse`